# Random File Opener

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I wrote  a random file opener in Python that takes file extensions as a tuple at code level, and directory/amount at console level:

```
import os
import random
import sys

class RandomFileOpener():

    def __init__(self, positives, file_exts):
        self.file_list_complete = []
        self.amount_to_open = 0 #So it can be checked if there's an existing entry
        self.selected_files = []
        self.positives = positives
        self.file_exts = file_exts
        self.open = False
        self.begin()

    def generate_file_array(self, directory):
        array = []
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower().endswith(self.file_exts):
                    array.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        return array            

    def random_choice(self, images, amount):
        return [random.choice(images) for i in range(0, len(images) if len(images) < amount else amount)]

    def open_files(self, selected_files):
        for file in selected_files:
            os.system("open " + file.replace(' ', '\ '))

    def begin(self):
        while True:
            if len(self.file_list_complete) == 0:
                self.file_list_complete = self.generate_file_array(str(input("Enter directory address: ")))
            if self.amount_to_open == 0:
                self.amount_to_open = int(input("Enter the amount of files you want: "))
            if len(self.selected_files) == 0:
                self.selected_files = self.random_choice(self.file_list_complete, self.amount_to_open)          
            if str(input("Do you want to open them? ").lower()) not in positives:
                print([file for file in self.selected_files])
            else:
                self.open_files(self.selected_files)

            if str(input("Do you want to do another? ").lower()) not in positives:
                sys.exit()
            self.begin()

positives = ["y", "yes", "sure"]
image_file_exts = ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.webm')
image_opener = RandomFileOpener(positives, image_file_exts)
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean to include a call to `self.begin` at the end of your `while` loop in `self.begin`?

```
def begin(self):
    while True:
        ...
        self.begin() # <-- Ruh-roh shaggy?
```

The `while` loop should already repeat the code contained in it, so the call to `self.begin` would only add more recursion-related issues into the mix.

The call to `str` here is redundant:

> ```
> str(input("Do you want to do another? ").lower())
> ```

If you're using Python 3.x, as I assumed from looking at your `print` statements, then you don't need to convert user input to a string. User input is already in a string format when it's obtained. The above code can simply become this:

```
input("Do you want to do another? ").lower()
```

In addition, there's no need for the parentheses when declaring a class in Python, as you've done here:

> ```
> class RandomFileOpener():
> ```

It can simply be declared like this:

```
class RandomFileOpener:
```

In older versions of Python, the parentheses, plus `object` inside the parentheses were required though in order to have a new-style class. In newer versions of Python though, all classes inherit from `object` by default.

Comment: Yes, I did mean to add the call at the end. That's mainly why I store the variables.

Comment: @Quill-HATMANIAC Huh? I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I ran your code without the recursive call to `begin` and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Oh, I see. Right. The `while` loop does that instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Checking things**

Prefer just `if lst:` to `if len(lst) == 0`. Prefer `if not self.amount_to_open` to comparing against 0.

**Recursive *and* Iterative**

`begin()` is both recursive and iterative. Pick one - iterative is good enough. Just have it loop until done:

```
def begin(self):
    while True:
        # there's a break somewhere in here, but no self.begin()
```

**Naming**

`begin()` doesn't just start doing something. It does everything - which is pretty unintuitive to say the least.

**Random choice**

This:

```
return [random.choice(images) for i in range(0, len(images) if len(images) < amount else amount)]
```

Is the same as:

```
return [random.choice(images) for i in range(0, min(len(images), amount))]
```

But could pick the same image lots of times. If you really want to sample, you'll want:

```
return random.sample(images, min(len(images), amount))
```

or:

```
try:
    return random.sample(images, amount)
except ValueError:
    return images
```

Comment: If `begin` does everything `run` would probably be a better name.